# Is it possible to insert image into database without using forms in php

Tags: php

i'm using a the following code to insert image into the database

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image">
<button type="submit" name="upload">Upload</button>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['upload']) && isset($_FILES['image']))
{
if(getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])==FALSE)
{
    echo "Please select an image";
}
else
{
    $image = addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
    $name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $image = file_get_contents($image);
    $image=base64_encode($image);                                               
}
}
//img_name(datatype: varchar) and img_content(datatype: longblob)
$SQL = "INSERT INTO image_db (img_name, img_content) VALUES ('$name', '$image')";

$result = mysqli_query($db_handle, $SQL);
?>
```

Is it possible to assign an image path from a folder in the local storge to a php variable and insert it into the database? I dont want to insert the path but i want to store the image in the variable in the specified path and insert it the same way as shown above.

For example:

```
<?php
    $image = "c:\images\default.png"
    $name = "default.png"
    $image = addslashes($image);
    $name = addslashes($name);
    $image = file_get_contents($image);
    $image=base64_encode($image);                                               

    $SQL = "INSERT INTO image_db (img_name, img_content) VALUES ('$name', '$image')";

    $result = mysqli_query($db_handle, $SQL);
?>
```

Please help me out. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: than how can u save the image physically in folder?

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. `addslashes()` is not, and have never been, a secure way to escape user input.

Comment: i want it in the database so that i can use the image as a default image for user profile

Comment: i know im open to SQL injection with the current code but right now i just want to the image to be inserted into the database as shown in the example

Comment: Save the image as a file on the server instead. It will save you a lot of headache (and increase performance), Just save it as "profile_xxx.jpg" or something, where you change the xxx to the users user id or username or what evs... Much easier and you don't need to do a db-call just to show an image.

Comment: If you want to upload a file, you need a form.